# Java- disable buttons on one jpanel with another.

Tags: java, swing

So my goal is to disable buttons on lets say panel B depending one what button they press on panel A. so below I have 2 combo boxes that id like to be able to enable or disable base on the buttons pressed on the first panel. Ive tried googling this problem but I'm new to java so its pretty rough going so far.

heres my sample code of what I'm trying to do.

```
package pack2;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

public class tessst {
    public boolean enableChk1;
    public boolean enableChk2;

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    tessst window = new tessst();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public tessst() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));




        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "name_15095567731094");
        panel.setLayout(null);

        final JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1, "name_15101078033315");
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JButton select2 = new JButton("2 boxes");
        select2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                enableChk1 = true;
                enableChk2 = true;
                panel_1.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
                panel_1.repaint();
                frame.repaint();
                panel.setVisible(false);
                panel_1.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        select2.setBounds(276, 101, 89, 23);
        panel.add(select2);

        JButton select1 = new JButton("1 boxes");
        select1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                enableChk1 = true;
                panel_1.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
                panel_1.repaint();
                frame.repaint();
                panel.setVisible(false);
                panel_1.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        select1.setBounds(59, 101, 89, 23);
        panel.add(select1);

        JButton select0 = new JButton("no boxes");
        select0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                enableChk1 = false;
                enableChk2 = false;
                panel_1.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
                panel_1.repaint();
                frame.repaint();
                panel.setVisible(false);
                panel_1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        select0.setBounds(166, 169, 89, 23);
        panel.add(select0);


        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setEnabled(enableChk1);
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"}));
        comboBox.setBounds(52, 100, 61, 20);
        panel_1.add(comboBox);

        JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox_1.setEnabled(enableChk2);
        comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"}));
        comboBox_1.setBounds(265, 100, 79, 20);
        panel_1.add(comboBox_1);

        JButton back = new JButton("go back");
        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                panel.setVisible(true);
                panel_1.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        back.setBounds(10, 227, 89, 23);
        panel_1.add(back);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you had any error messages, please edit the post with the errors and post your answer so others finding this question can benefit.

Comment: You need some kind of controller that controls the logic you need. You need some kind of model which maintains the state, so when you change the state of the first panel, it updates the model, which triggers a notification which other parts of your program can listen to and respond to. This lets the controller monitor the state of the model and update the second panel as required. Have a look at [Model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I needed to declare my comboBox's above my buttons then declare them as final.

Answer (score 0):

### here are the changes

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class tessst {
    public boolean enableChk1;
    public boolean enableChk2;
    JComboBox comboBox;
    JComboBox comboBox_1;

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    tessst window = new tessst();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public tessst() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));




        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "name_15095567731094");
        panel.setLayout(null);

        final JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1, "name_15101078033315");
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JButton select2 = new JButton("2 boxes");
        select2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                enableChk1 = true;
                enableChk2 = true;
                panel_1.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
                panel_1.repaint();
                frame.repaint();
                panel.setVisible(false);
                panel_1.setVisible(true);
                comboBox.setEnabled(true);
                comboBox_1.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });
        select2.setBounds(276, 101, 89, 23);
        panel.add(select2);

        JButton select1 = new JButton("1 boxes");
        select1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                enableChk1 = true;
                panel_1.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
                panel_1.repaint();
                frame.repaint();
                panel.setVisible(false);
                panel_1.setVisible(true);
                comboBox.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });
        select1.setBounds(59, 101, 89, 23);
        panel.add(select1);

        JButton select0 = new JButton("no boxes");
        select0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                enableChk1 = false;
                enableChk2 = false;
                panel_1.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
                panel_1.repaint();
                frame.repaint();
                panel.setVisible(false);
                panel_1.setVisible(true);
                comboBox.setEnabled(false);
                comboBox_1.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        select0.setBounds(166, 169, 89, 23);
        panel.add(select0);


        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setEnabled(enableChk1);
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"}));
        comboBox.setBounds(52, 100, 61, 20);
        panel_1.add(comboBox);

        comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox_1.setEnabled(enableChk2);
        comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"}));
        comboBox_1.setBounds(265, 100, 79, 20);
        panel_1.add(comboBox_1);

        JButton back = new JButton("go back");
        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                panel.setVisible(true);
                panel_1.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        back.setBounds(10, 227, 89, 23);
        panel_1.add(back);
    }
}
```

replace your code with this one. Its working Fine. Hope you are expecting this thing.